# "it was a pretty clear strategy from a handful of senators to try to cast her as ~"

Tags: sentence-structure

This is from [a news podcast](https://www.npr.org/2022/03/23/1088169655/morning-news-brief).

> SUSAN DAVIS, BYLINE: Well, it was a pretty clear strategy **from** a
> handful of senators to try to cast her as someone who would be soft on
> crime. Missouri Republican Senator Josh Hawley focused the entirety of
> his time on this one issue. Now, I should note, the White House
> criticized Hawley for flirting with conspiracies promoted by the QAnon
> movement that the Democratic Party is run by people who support or
> protect child predators. Here's some of his exchange.

If the 'from' in bold is changed to 'for', will 'a handful of senators' be the subject of the infinitive 'to try'?

If the 'from' in bold is kept as it is, does it mean that the strategy was just an opinion of a handful of senators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the more formal preposition to use here (with a very similar meaning) would be **by**:

> It was a clear **strategy** by a handful of senators to try to do X.

Which is just a slightly different formulation of:

> A handful of senators' clear strategy was to try to do X.

It's analogous to:

> We have seen an approach from the senators...

> We have seen an approach by the senators...

Comment: Thank you very much.